# what is wrong with my c# update code?

Tags: c#

i wrote code which has an id,year and status. status is a comb-box which has 4 item and when i try to run this code it keeps telling me like failed due toSyntax error in UPDATE statement, could you give me some idea please???

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            @"Data source= C:\crt_db.accdb";

        conn.Open();
        String year = dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString();
        String status = comboBox2.Text.ToString();
        String z =EPID.Text.ToString();

        String my_querry = "update crtRenewald set Year='" + year + "',Status='" + status+ "' where EPID=" + z + "";                
        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Status updated");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed due to" + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL statement?

Comment: `"update crtRenewald set Year='" + year + "',Status='" + status+ "' where EPID=" + z + ""` - shouldn't EPID=" + z + "" be `EPID='" + z '"`; also you have an extra " at the end of your line.

Comment: what is error msg. is EPID int or string ?

Comment: what's error that popped up

Comment: How is the table `crtRenewald` defined?

Comment: EPID is int, the popped up says failed due toSyntax error in UPDATE statement @AnuragJain.

Comment: crtReneald has an EPID, Year and status columns, also status has 4 choice which is new,Renew,suspend and withdrawal @AnuragJain

Comment: What datatype is Year ?

Comment: year is Date/time @Heslacher

Comment: So you shouldn't pass year as a string

Comment: okay how can i correct this String z =EPID.Text.ToString(); ???

Comment: That isn`t the problem, as you didn`t enclose the z into single quotes. Read this answer and the link inside the answer about sqlparameter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11053428/2655508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, May be it's help for you :-

I am using parameterized query according to your sql syntex.

```
     conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +@"Data source= C:\crt_db.accdb";

     conn.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        OleDbCommand scmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE crtRenewald SET Year=@Year, Status=@Status where @EPID=EPID", conn);
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Year", dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString());
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", comboBox2.Text.ToString());
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EPID", EPID.Text.ToString());

        scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }

     conn.Close();
```

Comment: i used access and tried to change it like                           using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    OleDbCommand sqlcmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE crtRenewald SET Year=@Year, Status=@Status where @EPID=EPID", conn);
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Year", dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", comboBox2.Text.ToString());
                    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EPID", EPID.Text.ToString());

                    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

Comment: @Biniam : So where is problem?

Comment: failed due toSyntax error in UPDATE statemnt

Comment: yeah it's steel shows a msgbox which tells me failed due toSyntax error in UPDATE statement

Comment: are you use my updated code ?

Comment: yes i tried it again and i got oleDbExeption was unhandled, syntax error in UPDATE statement, now i sow some progress.

Comment: your so close @Anurag Jain, please help me out with this thing :((

Comment: plz tell me, in which line your are face the error or if possible post your whole code in http://pastebin.com/ and send the link.

Comment: sure, on this line scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: and i did post code on pastebin.com http://pastebin.com/Y5F3sN3g

Comment: Most probably : Year ,Status or EPID contain null value or column name mismatch. check out at your end point

Comment: i past all the form code on http://pastebin.com/uVkf8Fqg thanks for your help @Anurag Jain i'll try to find some solution asap

Comment: On button3_Click , where you get the Year, Status or EPID value ?

Comment: Good: i get this values from datagridview, when you click a Row, the ID insert Date and Status will be filled and i use this code  if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];


                EPID.Text = row.Cells["EPID"].Value.ToString();
               dateTimePicker2.Text = row.Cells["Year"].Value.ToString();
             comboBox4.Text = row.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString();
             
            }

Comment: So here your question is different . you are taking those value from datatable but In your question , you are taking value from textbox. I post my answer according to your code or problem. if you are satisfy with my answer please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the quotes are incorrect in your UPDATE query string. Try changing it to:

```
String my_querry = "update crtRenewald set Year='" + year + "',Status='" + status + "' where EPID='" + z + "'";
```

Comment: EPID would be an int. so thats not required

Comment: i tryed exactly how you told me and i got same error failed due toSyntax error in UPDATE statement.